# htaccess url with question mark and backslash rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Sorry for so simple question, but can't make it work.

Need to rewrite

```
http://www.site.com/aaa.php/?bbb=ccc
```

into

```
http://www.site.com/aaa.php?bbb=ccc
```

note: question mark is changed from /? to ?

I tried something like :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (/?)bbb=([^&]+)
RewriteRule /?(.*) %1/$1 [R=301]
```

Thanks )

Comment: Could it not be easier to remove the `/` in the code if possible? or is aaa.php a dir?

Comment: Not in mine case. A lot of includes and conditions. Somehow it starts the loop.

Comment: I have the perfectly working code. When spammers grab content all around, then in many cases they accidentally rewrite the links on the pages they grab. So they posted spun content with incorrect links somewhere. Then bots crawl this content, follow incorrect links, run the page into the loop, stats are going crazy. Conclusion: I don't want to touch perfectly working code because of this (but I tried)). However I totally forgot how to Rewrite. Wasted three hours already. Help !!! ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [QSA]
```

See [docs for QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

EDIT:

To redirect and make the URL look nice in the browser bar:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Same URL. Thanks anyway)

Comment: It is internal. Are you trying to redirect?

Comment: Nope. Need it internal from URL with /? to URL with ?